# Heroku fails to install pywin32 library

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to push my Python application to Heroku but it looks like `pywin32` isn't being installed:

```
Counting objects: 519, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (483/483), done.
Writing objects: 100% (519/519), 7.55 MiB | 136.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 519 (delta 247), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting aioredis==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/15/79bc11213e1b918f152914e1de96e5610961da3709e3ca8cc650e00b8f4e/aioredis-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (59kB)
remote:        Collecting amqp==2.1.4 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/4b/ac7afb11b57f237e3c1c64b5408c5d229bf5d4b42af6cb6e683c7690ca4f/amqp-2.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49kB)
remote:        Collecting asgi-redis==1.4.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/06/25/c1194af4c5599787cbdb11071bca584e4ccf683f0f97bdafc6a9deaedd6d/asgi_redis-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting asgiref==1.1.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/6d/67f79a9567de5ba4419c3e8d39622bed0d974d704075d09df765b5ddb5ce/asgiref-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting asn1crypto==0.24.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (101kB)
remote:        Collecting astroid==1.6.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cb/8c/18fefaf865c3e48ed31d60d53a8f85ba7e8b27fe9bd115cecae876a8d58e/astroid-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (288kB)
remote:        Collecting async-timeout==2.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/b9/213521db2918b5b7f7df333a33ea3d38ba70ba705d9db6c29f0343c213ea/async_timeout-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting attrs==17.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/ff/2d0c4483443789477022d85ab467bc4c0f18c6d45cb02234ed64048cbb33/attrs-17.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting autobahn==17.6.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/8f/ed2947ea6f0bb16b9131da972b0e4caaf775b30267d7110ebe1188353256/autobahn-17.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (271kB)
remote:        Collecting Automat==0.6.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/6a/1baf488c2015ecafda48c03ca984cf0c48c254622668eb1732dbe2eae118/Automat-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting billiard==3.5.0.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/56/90fd158263e324742fb0ac82f9e2650dbbc7f93a233d9e254021e5d35880/billiard-3.5.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (102kB)
remote:        Collecting bleach==2.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 12))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/76/45/d3f5e5553340286dfceb7eedffd42afa9829011e79175900609cf359cf5f/bleach-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting celery==4.0.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 13))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/46/3524d4730d3217960b5e32cb8b202420af8714e2b123b9f95882e1fb2067/celery-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (396kB)
remote:        Collecting certifi==2017.4.17 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 14))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/eb/01/c1f58987b777d6c4ec535b4e004a4a07bfc9db06f0c7533367ca6da8f2a6/certifi-2017.4.17-py2.py3-none-any.whl (375kB)
remote:        Collecting cffi==1.11.5 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 15))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6d/c0/47db8f624f3e4e2f3f27be03a93379d1ba16a1450a7b1aacfa0366e2c0dd/cffi-1.11.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (421kB)
remote:        Collecting channels==1.1.3 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/7c/60ec0b200566bae62a1b21d113c5063d14d9982c266f69f896f6023c3b1e/channels-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (52kB)
remote:        Collecting channels-redis==2.1.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 17))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9d/74/1cd3c99a63dd15503b1426140815f1f01c04cd298b3c5e8c83dbee75089f/channels_redis-2.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting chardet==3.0.4 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 18))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/a9/01ffebfb562e4274b6487b4bb1ddec7ca55ec7510b22e4c51f14098443b8/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
remote:        Collecting colorama==0.3.9 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 19))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/c8/7dcf9dbcb22429512708fe3a547f8b6101c0d02137acbd892505aee57adf/colorama-0.3.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting constantly==15.1.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 20))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/65/48c1909d0c0aeae6c10213340ce682db01b48ea900a7d9fce7a7910ff318/constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting cryptography==2.2.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 21))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/68/0168a440e61b08938c56859afdc320a5836316e37222a98b4a6950fab3b0/cryptography-2.2.1-cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2MB)
remote:        Collecting daphne==1.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 22))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/4c/755272e0a0fd01ed15c725f37957cdc4c5971f60336e23c48deda5f0c530/daphne-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 23))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/a6/4b8578c1848690d0c307c7c0596af2077536c9ef2a04d42b00fabaa7e49d/dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting Django==1.11.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 24))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/e6/4ac2f5c9bdc9c82eb48e86a6190e2579be3d10c1afe457993c54cb7d5bc5/Django-1.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
remote:        Collecting django-bleach==0.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 25))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/12/3a6ec6d8aae68562a9c662f0e2fd15da3d85f681cc759852b2ac40e9db43/django-bleach-0.3.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting django-celery-beat==1.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 26))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dc/4b/9a4a8b59d8bce0d6efd5e8733429b5604085a27536cd9061ddf3d65d69e2/django_celery_beat-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting django-channels-presence==0.0.7 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 27))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/a1/a2327160d2fe7f79aa13cc2d1694780468a99660d2363c792ad7934884f1/django-channels-presence-0.0.7.tar.gz (176kB)
remote:        Collecting django-environ==0.4.4 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 28))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0e/04/8a2b9d21ed73761b8e12201aa0531c0b0971fe8a832c9311cb3c2529fa98/django_environ-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting django-postmark==0.1.6 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 29))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/6f/34e5ff36eabeee286d0fe029e72f84b51b1a352906244474bd4172543ecc/django-postmark-0.1.6.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 30))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/76/9fd5b014efb237598ba05f1d89dfde6c573aeb86b173f9c59327e8b8abb9/django_widget_tweaks-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.7.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 31))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/32/becbd4089a4c06f0f9f538a76e9fe0b19a08f010bcb47dcdbfbc640cdf7d/gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111kB)
remote:        Collecting h2==3.0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 32))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/2b/833e258072d47865b99dc0810475481d6371e3d3bfede9251ca27035e30f/h2-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
remote:        Collecting hiredis==0.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 33))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/98/4766d85124b785ff1989ee1c79631a1b6ecfcb444ff39999a87877b2027e/hiredis-0.2.0.tar.gz (46kB)
remote:        Collecting hpack==3.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 34))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8a/cc/e53517f4a1e13f74776ca93271caef378dadec14d71c61c949d759d3db69/hpack-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting html5lib==0.999999999 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 35))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/71/a96f36d34394bcfff9fb54bfe0aa72cc5b4ff2f803e5728645aef38f7aee/html5lib-0.999999999-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
remote:        Collecting httplib2==0.11.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 36))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a0/15/964b7ff08a126c620444dc3e5978edaadabca2ad6cb7621b7a82cd7f9eab/httplib2-0.11.0.tar.gz (216kB)
remote:        Collecting hyperframe==5.1.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 37))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/44/23/e9b5095440ccac7f8ecd72a90dbd0a38791f5f2134a329e2f331b7e64c58/hyperframe-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting hyperlink==17.1.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 38))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/d5/c4c6262646a2cfcbd32b0cbe5bf04a6be2bcdf24403ec3429dea0183ddc7/hyperlink-17.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55kB)
remote:        Collecting idna==2.5 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 39))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/11/7d/9bbbd7bb35f34b0169542487d2a8859e44306bb2e6a4455d491800a5621f/idna-2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55kB)
remote:        Collecting incremental==17.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 40))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1d/c98a587dc06e107115cf4a58b49de20b19222c83d75335a192052af4c4b7/incremental-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting isort==4.3.3 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 41))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/03/8377124671d0c7c80a9bc2b5f5fc30b5784f7739dba7ce41458ef00ba7de/isort-4.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (45kB)
remote:        Collecting kombu==4.0.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 42))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/ac/567da3770c8f1d2c44262b485130d6a12efc1bdb4ba79f1f328e1015ecd0/kombu-4.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178kB)
remote:        Collecting lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 43))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/65/1f/2043ec33066e779905ed7e6580384425fdc7dc2ac64d6931060c75b0c5a3/lazy_object_proxy-1.3.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (55kB)
remote:        Collecting Markdown==2.6.8 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 44))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/25/3f6d2cb31ec42ca5bd3bfbea99b63892b735d76e26f20dd2dcc34ffe4f0d/Markdown-2.6.8.tar.gz (307kB)
remote:        Collecting mccabe==0.6.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 45))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/89/479dc97e18549e21354893e4ee4ef36db1d237534982482c3681ee6e7b57/mccabe-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting msgpack==0.5.6 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 46))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/4e/dcf124fd97e5f5611123d6ad9f40ffd6eb979d1efdc1049e28a795672fcd/msgpack-0.5.6-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (315kB)
remote:        Collecting msgpack-python==0.4.8 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 47))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/27/8a1d82041c7a2a51fcc73675875a5f9ea06c2663e02fcfeb708be1d081a0/msgpack-python-0.4.8.tar.gz (113kB)
remote:        Collecting Pillow==5.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 48))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/2f/86941111d108fd060190c994f15881283b98693c1c370e74885cfc470eb3/Pillow-5.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.9MB)
remote:        Collecting postmarker==0.11.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 49))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/dd/5b/b2dcb1cd6e3e745f2ebc4c8a7b6e73d5338b0fcdf981a858f4af65c78a72/postmarker-0.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting priority==1.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 50))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/de/96/2f4b8da7be255cd41e825c398efd11a6706ff86e66ae198f012204aa2a4f/priority-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.7.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 51))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/90/bb/fd1a81e1a51b2df2d825e778fd58d508a4fc9ab360684348222bda3ff704/psycopg2-2.7.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7MB)
remote:        Collecting pyasn1==0.4.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 52))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/fe/02e3e2ee243966b143657fb8bd6bc97595841163b6d8c26820944acaec4d/pyasn1-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
remote:        Collecting pyasn1-modules==0.2.1 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 53))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/51/bcd96bf6231d4b2cc5e023c511bee86637ba375c44a6f9d1b4b7ad1ce4b9/pyasn1_modules-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60kB)
remote:        Collecting pycparser==2.18 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 54))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/2d/aad7f16146f4197a11f8e91fb81df177adcc2073d36a17b1491fd09df6ed/pycparser-2.18.tar.gz (245kB)
remote:        Collecting pylint==1.8.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 55))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/fe/32faf5617f1b32478c626f93ad533d06b59d2663521403799aac408789ef/pylint-1.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (689kB)
remote:        Collecting pyOpenSSL==17.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 56))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/db/7c0cfe4aa8341a5fab4638952520d8db6ab85ff84505e12c00ea311c3516/pyOpenSSL-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53kB)
remote:        Collecting pypiwin32==223 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 57))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d0/1b/2f292bbd742e369a100c91faa0483172cd91a1a422a6692055ac920946c5/pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting pytz==2017.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 58))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/62/e7cd0e15b76062d298413f14bb4ec3cd8568a22d274427f9c3c7286969f4/pytz-2017.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (484kB)
remote:        Collecting pywin32==223 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 59))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==223 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 59)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for pywin32==223 (from -r /tmp/build_9cc549609c727e83c7b487b43fec0a2e/requirements.txt (line 59))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to fast-citadel-12918.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/fast-citadel-12918.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fast-citadel-12918.git'
```

I'm developing on Windows 10 Professional, and the application works fine there. My `requirements.txt contains:

```
aioredis==1.0.0
amqp==2.1.4
asgi-redis==1.4.0
asgiref==1.1.2
asn1crypto==0.24.0
astroid==1.6.1
async-timeout==2.0.1
attrs==17.2.0
autobahn==17.6.1
Automat==0.6.0
billiard==3.5.0.2
bleach==2.0.0
celery==4.0.2
certifi==2017.4.17
cffi==1.11.5
channels==1.1.3
channels-redis==2.1.1
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.2.1
daphne==1.2.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==1.11.2
django-bleach==0.3.0
django-celery-beat==1.0.1
django-channels-presence==0.0.7
django-environ==0.4.4
django-postmark==0.1.6
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
gunicorn==19.7.1
h2==3.0.1
hiredis==0.2.0
hpack==3.0.0
html5lib==0.999999999
httplib2==0.11.0
hyperframe==5.1.0
hyperlink==17.1.1
idna==2.5
incremental==17.5.0
isort==4.3.3
kombu==4.0.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
Markdown==2.6.8
mccabe==0.6.1
msgpack==0.5.6
msgpack-python==0.4.8
Pillow==5.0.0
postmarker==0.11.2
priority==1.3.0
psycopg2==2.7.1
pyasn1==0.4.2
pyasn1-modules==0.2.1
pycparser==2.18
pylint==1.8.2
pyOpenSSL==17.5.0
pypiwin32==223
pytz==2017.2
pywin32==223
redis==2.10.5
requests==2.17.3
selenium==3.11.0
service-identity==17.0.0
six==1.10.0
Twisted==17.5.0
txaio==2.8.0
urllib3==1.21.1
vine==1.1.3
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==0.47.0
whitenoise==3.3.1
wrapt==1.10.11
zope.interface==4.4.1
```

Why can't Heroku install `pywin32`?

Comment: i notice that  pywin32 can't be found for some reason but i have no idea how to fix this, but i'm certain that is more a python or django problem

Answer (score 14):

From [its README](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32):

> This is the readme for the Python for Win32 (pywin32) extensions, which provides access to many of the Windows APIs from Python.

Heroku doesn't run on Windows, so there are no Windows APIs available. As a result `pywin32` can't be installed.

You either have to host your application on Windows or remove the `pywin32` dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing on that dependency you can use
`pywin32==301; platform_system == "Windows"` to conditionally install it on on Windows

Answer (score 2):

I have got same issue while deploying `python` script in to `heroku`. For me its working by removing below entries in `requirements.txt`

```
pypiwin32==223
pywin32==223
```

Below `python` version installed by default

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it from the requirements.txt file