# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==227 heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am having this issue with heroku.
i am trying to push my application to heroku  but 
it seems that heroku can not install pywin32=227 but i do not know why is this happening.
i hope that someone can help me whit this issue.

Requirements.txt:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
asgiref==3.2.3
awsebcli==3.17.1
botocore==1.14.17
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.3.9
distlib==0.3.0
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.15
django-pyodbc-azure==2.1.0.0
docutils==0.15.2
filelock==3.0.12
future==0.16.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.7
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
jmespath==0.9.5
pathspec==0.5.9
Pillow==7.0.0
psycopg2==2.8.4
pyodbc==4.0.30
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-decouple==3.3
pytz==2019.3
pywin32==227
PyYAML==5.2
requests==2.20.1
semantic-version==2.5.0
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
stripe==2.43.0
termcolor==1.1.0
urllib3==1.24.3
virtualenv==20.0.7
wcwidth==0.1.8
whitenoise==5.0.1
zipp==3.1.0
```

I'm developing on Windows 10 Professional, and the application works fine there:

```
C:\Users\GuGarza\test>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 363, done.
Counting objects: 100% (363/363), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (348/348), done.
Writing objects: 100% (363/363), 257.21 KiB | 1.42 MiB/s, done.
Total 363 (delta 107), reused 0 (delta 0)

remote:          Downloading pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==227 (from -r 
/tmp/build_000de559e8272ea11b28b5ee568bf649/requirements.txt (line 28)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==227 (from -r 
/tmp/build_000de559e8272ea11b28b5ee568bf649/requirements.txt (line 28))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to memotion.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/memotion.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/memotion.git'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku fails to install pywin32 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026190/heroku-fails-to-install-pywin32-library)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the same error while deploying flask app in azure app server.

Removing/commentting out `pywin32==227` in `requirements.txt` worked for me.

Comment: i still do not know why this happened but i solved the issue moving my application to another computer and then deploying it to heroku. I hope that our comments will save time and mental health to other people with the same issue.

Comment: You saved my day!

Answer (score 7):

Conditional dependencies is a better choice in this situation. This way you don't break things on Windows.

Add `;platform_system == "Windows"` right after the Windows-only packages

Comment: So the line should look like `pywin32==227;platform_system == "Windows"`. See [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers) for more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Pycharm.

Installing new version or packages like pypiwin32 did not work as described above.
Removing packages from the req file did not work either.

I copied my dev files, then I deleted the project.
I set up a completely new project and copied the Py files into it.
It worked.

The cause for the error message above was:

I did corrupt my project by trying to install chart_studio with pip, which did not work. It only works with Conda.
This corrupted my req and my site packages.