# Unable to Deploy Django App to Heroku because of PyWin32

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, pip

So I have gone through the forums in search for an answer but haven't found one that works for me.
I am using Windows machine and my Django application works on Localhost but when I try to deploy the same application to Heroku it gives me this error.

```
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of anyio to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
```

I have removed `pywin32` from the **requirements.txt** file but still when I run the

```
git push heroku master
```

command, I keep getting the same error.

I have also tried to copy all my source code into a new folder and deleted the initial `git` file and re-initialized Git but still nothing seems to be working.

Forum Articles I have read that did not help include:

- [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==227 heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747943/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pywin32-227-heroku)
- [Heroku fails to install pywin32 library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026190/heroku-fails-to-install-pywin32-library)

Allow me to attach my full `error log`:

```
Enumerating objects: 268, done.
Counting objects: 100% (268/268), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (259/259), done.
Writing objects: 100% (268/268), 377.32 KiB | 4.49 MiB/s, done.
Total 268 (delta 147), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> No Python version was specified. Using the buildpack default: python-3.9.8
remote:        To use a different version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.9.8
remote: -----> Installing pip 21.3.1, setuptools 57.5.0 and wheel 0.37.0
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Ignoring pywin32: markers 'platform_system == "Windows"' don't match your environment
remote:        Collecting anyio==3.3.0
remote:          Downloading anyio-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
remote:        Collecting argon2-cffi==20.1.0
remote:          Downloading argon2_cffi-20.1.0-cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (97 kB)
remote:        Collecting asgiref==3.4.1
remote:          Downloading asgiref-3.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
remote:        Collecting attrs==21.2.0
remote:          Downloading attrs-21.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
remote:        Collecting autopep8==1.5.7
remote:          Downloading autopep8-1.5.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
remote:        Collecting Babel==2.9.1
remote:          Downloading Babel-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
remote:        Collecting backcall==0.2.0
remote:          Downloading backcall-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
remote:          Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.9.3-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
remote:        Collecting bleach==4.0.0
remote:          Downloading bleach-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (146 kB)
remote:        Collecting branca==0.4.2
remote:          Downloading branca-0.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
remote:        Collecting certifi==2021.5.30
remote:          Downloading certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
remote:        Collecting cffi==1.14.6
remote:          Downloading cffi-1.14.6-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (405 kB)
remote:        Collecting charset-normalizer==2.0.4
remote:          Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
remote:        Collecting click==8.0.1
remote:          Downloading click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
remote:        Collecting click-plugins==1.1.1
remote:          Downloading click_plugins-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting cligj==0.7.2
remote:          Downloading cligj-0.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.1 kB)
remote:        Collecting colorama==0.4.4
remote:          Downloading colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting cryptography==3.4.7
remote:          Downloading cryptography-3.4.7-cp36-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting cycler==0.10.0
remote:          Downloading cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting debugpy==1.4.1
remote:          Downloading debugpy-1.4.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting decorator==5.0.9
remote:          Downloading decorator-5.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (8.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting defusedxml==0.7.1
remote:          Downloading defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.5.0
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting Django==3.2.9
remote:          Downloading Django-3.2.9-py3-none-any.whl (7.9 MB)
remote:        Collecting django-crispy-forms==1.12.0
remote:          Downloading django_crispy_forms-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (122 kB)
remote:        Collecting django-heroku==0.3.1
remote:          Downloading django_heroku-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting django-taggit==1.5.1
remote:          Downloading django_taggit-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
remote:        Collecting docopt==0.6.2
remote:          Downloading docopt-0.6.2.tar.gz (25 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting entrypoints==0.3
remote:          Downloading entrypoints-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting folium==0.12.1
remote:          Downloading folium-0.12.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
remote:        Collecting future==0.18.2
remote:          Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting geocoder==1.38.1
remote:          Downloading geocoder-1.38.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
remote:        Collecting geographiclib==1.52
remote:          Downloading geographiclib-1.52-py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
remote:        Collecting geopy==2.2.0
remote:          Downloading geopy-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (118 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
remote:        Collecting idna==3.2
remote:          Downloading idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
remote:        Collecting importlib-metadata==4.6.4
remote:          Downloading importlib_metadata-4.6.4-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
remote:        Collecting ipykernel==6.2.0
remote:          Downloading ipykernel-6.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (122 kB)
remote:        Collecting ipython==7.26.0
remote:          Downloading ipython-7.26.0-py3-none-any.whl (786 kB)
remote:        Collecting ipython-genutils==0.2.0
remote:          Downloading ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
remote:        Collecting ipywidgets==7.6.3
remote:          Downloading ipywidgets-7.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
remote:        Collecting jedi==0.18.0
remote:          Downloading jedi-0.18.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==3.0.1
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
remote:        Collecting Js2Py==0.71
remote:          Downloading Js2Py-0.71-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting json5==0.9.6
remote:          Downloading json5-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting jsonschema==3.2.0
remote:          Downloading jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
remote:        Collecting jupyter-client==7.0.1
remote:          Downloading jupyter_client-7.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (122 kB)
remote:        Collecting jupyter-core==4.7.1
remote:          Downloading jupyter_core-4.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
remote:        Collecting jupyter-server==1.10.2
remote:          Downloading jupyter_server-1.10.2-py3-none-any.whl (392 kB)
remote:        Collecting jupyterlab==3.1.7
remote:          Downloading jupyterlab-3.1.7-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting jupyterlab-pygments==0.1.2
remote:          Downloading jupyterlab_pygments-0.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting jupyterlab-server==2.7.2
remote:          Downloading jupyterlab_server-2.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
remote:        Collecting jupyterlab-widgets==1.0.0
remote:          Downloading jupyterlab_widgets-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (243 kB)
remote:        Collecting keyring==23.1.0
remote:          Downloading keyring-23.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
remote:        Collecting kiwisolver==1.3.1
remote:          Downloading kiwisolver-1.3.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting lerc==0.1.0
remote:          Downloading lerc-0.1.0.tar.gz (567 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (30 kB)
remote:        Collecting matplotlib==3.4.3
remote:          Downloading matplotlib-3.4.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.3 MB)
remote:        Collecting matplotlib-inline==0.1.2
remote:          Downloading matplotlib_inline-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
remote:        Collecting mistune==0.8.4
remote:          Downloading mistune-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting munch==2.5.0
remote:          Downloading munch-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
remote:        Collecting nbclassic==0.3.1
remote:          Downloading nbclassic-0.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting nbclient==0.5.4
remote:          Downloading nbclient-0.5.4-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
remote:        Collecting nbconvert==6.1.0
remote:          Downloading nbconvert-6.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (551 kB)
remote:        Collecting nbformat==5.1.3
remote:          Downloading nbformat-5.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
remote:        Collecting nest-asyncio==1.5.1
remote:          Downloading nest_asyncio-1.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
remote:        Collecting notebook==6.4.3
remote:          Downloading notebook-6.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (9.9 MB)
remote:        Collecting ntlm-auth==1.5.0
remote:          Downloading ntlm_auth-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
remote:        Collecting numpy==1.21.4
remote:          Downloading numpy-1.21.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
remote:        Collecting oauthlib==3.1.1
remote:          Downloading oauthlib-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (146 kB)
remote:        Collecting packaging==21.0
remote:          Downloading packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
remote:        Collecting pandas==1.3.2
remote:          Downloading pandas-1.3.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.5 MB)
remote:        Collecting pandocfilters==1.4.3
remote:          Downloading pandocfilters-1.4.3.tar.gz (16 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting parso==0.8.2
remote:          Downloading parso-0.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
remote:        Collecting pickleshare==0.7.5
remote:          Downloading pickleshare-0.7.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 kB)
remote:        Collecting Pillow==8.3.1
remote:          Downloading Pillow-8.3.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting prometheus-client==0.11.0
remote:          Downloading prometheus_client-0.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
remote:        Collecting prompt-toolkit==3.0.20
remote:          Downloading prompt_toolkit-3.0.20-py3-none-any.whl (370 kB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.9.1
remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.9.1.tar.gz (379 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
remote:          Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.9.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.4 MB)
remote:        Collecting pycodestyle==2.7.0
remote:          Downloading pycodestyle-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
remote:        Collecting pycparser==2.20
remote:          Downloading pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
remote:        Collecting Pygments==2.10.0
remote:          Downloading Pygments-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting pyjsparser==2.7.1
remote:          Downloading pyjsparser-2.7.1.tar.gz (24 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7
remote:          Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
remote:        Collecting PyPrind==2.11.3
remote:          Downloading PyPrind-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.4 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyproj==3.1.0
remote:          Downloading pyproj-3.1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (6.6 MB)
remote:        Collecting pyrsistent==0.18.0
remote:          Downloading pyrsistent-0.18.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (117 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyshp==2.1.3
remote:          Downloading pyshp-2.1.3.tar.gz (219 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting pySmartDL==1.3.4
remote:          Downloading pySmartDL-1.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-dateutil==2.8.2
remote:          Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
remote:        Collecting python-decouple==3.4
remote:          Downloading python_decouple-3.4-py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz==2021.1
remote:          Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
remote:        Collecting pyzmq==22.2.1
remote:          Downloading pyzmq-22.2.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
remote:        Collecting ratelim==0.1.6
remote:          Downloading ratelim-0.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.0 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests==2.26.0
remote:          Downloading requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests-kerberos==0.12.0
remote:          Downloading requests_kerberos-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests-negotiate-sspi==0.5.2
remote:          Downloading requests_negotiate_sspi-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.1 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests-ntlm==1.1.0
remote:          Downloading requests_ntlm-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
remote:          Downloading requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
remote:          Downloading requests_toolbelt-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
remote:        Collecting requests-unixsocket==0.2.0
remote:          Downloading requests_unixsocket-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting Send2Trash==1.8.0
remote:          Downloading Send2Trash-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting setuptools-scm==6.0.1
remote:          Downloading setuptools_scm-6.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
remote:        Collecting Shapely==1.7.1
remote:          Downloading Shapely-1.7.1-1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
remote:        Collecting six==1.16.0
remote:          Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting sniffio==1.2.0
remote:          Downloading sniffio-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
remote:        Collecting soupsieve==2.2.1
remote:          Downloading soupsieve-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
remote:        Collecting sqlparse==0.4.1
remote:          Downloading sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
remote:        Collecting terminado==0.11.1
remote:          Downloading terminado-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
remote:        Collecting testpath==0.5.0
remote:          Downloading testpath-0.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
remote:        Collecting toml==0.10.2
remote:          Downloading toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting tornado==6.1
remote:          Downloading tornado-6.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (427 kB)
remote:        Collecting traitlets==5.0.5
remote:          Downloading traitlets-5.0.5-py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
remote:        Collecting tzdata==2021.1
remote:          Downloading tzdata-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (338 kB)
remote:        Collecting tzlocal==3.0
remote:          Downloading tzlocal-3.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
remote:        Collecting ujson==4.1.0
remote:          Downloading ujson-4.1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (179 kB)
remote:        Collecting urllib3==1.26.6
remote:          Downloading urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
remote:        Collecting wcwidth==0.2.5
remote:          Downloading wcwidth-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
remote:        Collecting webencodings==0.5.1
remote:          Downloading webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
remote:        Collecting websocket-client==1.2.1
remote:          Downloading websocket_client-1.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==5.3.0
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-5.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
remote:        Collecting widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
remote:          Downloading widgetsnbextension-3.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.2 MB)
remote:        Collecting winkerberos==0.8.0
remote:          Downloading winkerberos-0.8.0.zip (44 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting wrapt==1.12.1
remote:          Downloading wrapt-1.12.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting zipp==3.5.0
remote:          Downloading zipp-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
remote:        Collecting pexpect>4.3
remote:          Downloading pexpect-4.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
remote:        Collecting SecretStorage>=3.2
remote:          Downloading SecretStorage-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
remote:        Collecting jeepney>=0.4.2
remote:          Downloading jeepney-0.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
remote:        Collecting pykerberos<2.0.0,>=1.1.8
remote:          Downloading pykerberos-1.2.1.tar.gz (24 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        Collecting pypiwin32>=223
remote:          Downloading pypiwin32-223-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 kB)
remote:        Collecting ptyprocess
remote:          Downloading ptyprocess-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pykerberos to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting pykerberos<2.0.0,>=1.1.8
remote:          Downloading pykerberos-1.1.14.tar.gz (20 kB)
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
remote:          Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of ptyprocess to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting ptyprocess
remote:          Downloading ptyprocess-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pexpect to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting pexpect>4.3
remote:          Downloading pexpect-4.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of jeepney to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        Collecting jeepney>=0.4.2
remote:          Downloading jeepney-0.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of zipp to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of geographiclib to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.        
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of geocoder to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of future to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of folium to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of entrypoints to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of docopt to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-taggit to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.        
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-heroku to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.        
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-crispy-forms to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.  
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of dj-database-url to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.      
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of defusedxml to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of decorator to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of debugpy to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cycler to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cryptography to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of colorama to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cligj to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of click-plugins to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.        
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of click to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of charset-normalizer to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.   
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cffi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of certifi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of branca to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of bleach to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of beautifulsoup4 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.       
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of backcall to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of babel to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of autopep8 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of attrs to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of asgiref to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of argon2-cffi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of anyio to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 5876ebd1f6928d422590ee2bced6db875179e28e
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 5876ebd1f6928d422590ee2bced6db875179e28e
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to djangogis.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/djangogis.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/djangogis.git'
```

and then my [requirements file](https://github.com/Surveyor-Jr/django_gis/blob/master/requirements.txt)

Anyone who can help me I would really appreciate. Where exactly am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @phd from the requirements.txt file in the question, can you kindly assist by stating which dependency might be leading to the reinstalling of pywin32 even when it is not in the requirements.txt file? I am failing to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current `requirements.txt` you marked `pywin32` with environment marker `platform_system == "Windows"`. I think the syntax is wrong. The correct syntax from [PEP 496](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0496/#examples) is:

```
pywin32==223; sys_platform == "win32"
```

Comment: I am still having the same problem even if I use this syntax. I guess mine is a major problem that requires going through all contents in the requirements one by one trying to find which one might be causing this error.

Comment: So I managed to figure out a temporary work out for deployment. I installed django in a separate virtual-env and collected all the requirements that come with django. I then manually added all my imported modules until the app was complete. I figured during development, there were some packages that were installed but never used and the work had become cluttered. Have somewhere to start now. Thank you for the assistance and time.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while trying to deploy my Django project to Heroku. The reason for this error is because pywin32 can only run on windows os.
What needs to be done to fix this problem is to uninstall pywin32 using the following cmd snippet.

> `python pip -y uninstall pywin32`

Try redeploying your Django app all over again. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, deploying from Visual Studio to Heroku (via the cli).
What finally worked for me, was to upgrade my packages in the (VS) Python environment. `pip install pypiwin32 --upgrade` and `pip install pywin32 --upgrade` (think it is now at version 304).
Regenerate the requirements.txt file (or manually update it) and the commit it to git hub.
To redeploy to heroku :

```
pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

once that was completed,

```
git push heroku main
```

completed successfully, and my app deployed.

Answer (score 0):

After removing pywin32 from the requirements, do a git add and commit to update your commit then push to heroku. I just encountered the same issue and I got it solved this way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).