# Error regarding git push heroku main command, pywin32 error

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, heroku-cli

When I am trying to push my new project, I have the following errors when  I run git push heroku main in my terminal:

```
remote:        INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of pypiwin32 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
remote:        ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.9.5 Requires-Python >=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, <3.
7
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

This is my `requirements.txt` file

```
asgiref==3.3.2
astroid==2.4.2
asttokens==2.2.1
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.9.3
bootstrap4==0.1.0
boto==2.49.0
boto3==1.17.101
botocore==1.20.101
cffi==1.14.5
chromelogger==0.4.3
colorama==0.4.4
comm==0.1.2
debugpy==1.6.6
decorator==5.1.1
distro==1.5.0
dj-database-url==2.0.0
Django==3.2
django-bootstrap3==14.2.0
django-bootstrap4==3.0.1
django-braces==1.14.0
django-crispy-forms==1.11.2
django-debug-toolbar==3.2.1
django-developer-panel==0.1.2
django-misaka==0.2.1
django-storages==1.11.1
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
executing==1.2.0
google-compute-engine==2.8.13
gunicorn==20.1.0
houdini.py==0.1.0
importlib-metadata==6.0.0
ipykernel==6.21.2
ipython==8.10.0
isort==5.7.0
jedi==0.18.0
jmespath==0.10.0
jsonpickle==2.0.0
jupyter_client==8.0.3
jupyter_core==5.2.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
matplotlib-inline==0.1.6
mccabe==0.6.1
misaka==2.1.1
nest-asyncio==1.5.6
numpy==1.24.2
ordereddict==1.1
packaging==23.0
pandas==1.5.3
parso==0.8.1
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.2.0
platformdirs==3.0.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.37
psutil==5.9.4
psycopg2==2.9.6
psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
pure-eval==0.2.2
pycparser==2.20
Pygments==2.9.0
pylint==2.6.0
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
pywin32==305
pyzmq==25.0.0
s3transfer==0.4.2
six==1.15.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
sqlparse==0.4.1
stack-data==0.6.2
toml==0.10.2
tornado==6.2
traitlets==5.9.0
typing_extensions==4.5.0
tzdata==2023.3
urllib3==1.26.6
wcwidth==0.2.6
whitenoise==5.2.0
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.14.0
```

And also I am using **python-3.9.16** in my `runtime.txt` file. How can I resolve this? It is getting very annoying, I have tried to switch the versions but I am still getting the same errors over and over again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here seems to be that [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/), the module you are trying to install, is not compatible with Heroku, which is a Linux-based platform.
pywin32 is a set of Python extensions for Windows, and as such, they are not compatible with non-Windows platforms like Heroku.

In your `requirements.txt` file, you are specifying to install `pypiwin32==223` and `pywin32==305`, which won't work on Heroku.

As [noted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68590752/6309), you can  use the environment markers in Python to conditionally install packages based on the system platform.

In your `requirements.txt`, you can specify that `pywin32` and `pypiwin32` should only be installed on Windows by adding `; platform_system == "Windows"` to the end of those lines.  This way, when Heroku (a Linux system) reads the file, it will skip these packages.

Your `requirements.txt` file should look like this:

```
...
# Other dependencies
...
pypiwin32==223; platform_system == "Windows"
pywin32==305; platform_system == "Windows"
...
# Other dependencies
...
```

By doing this, `pywin32` and `pypiwin32` will only be installed if the `platform_system` is "Windows". When Heroku tries to install the dependencies, it should ignore these two.

After modifying the `requirements.txt` file, commit the changes and push to Heroku again:

```bash
git add requirements.txt
git commit -m "Conditionally install Windows-specific packages"
git push heroku main
```